# Can you add filters in JPEG file?

Tags: python, svg, jpeg, encode

Is it possible to convert JPEG file back to SVG file and be able to edit SVG Filters on it; something like reverse engineering? If so how would I do it on PYTHON?

I am using this for converting JPEG to SVG

```
def ConvertImage(filename):
    startSvgTag = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="240px" height="240px" viewBox="0 0 240 240">"""
    endSvgTag = """</svg>"""
    defs = """<defs>"""
    end_defs = """</defs>"""
    pngFile = open(filename, 'rb')
    base64data = pngFile.read().encode("base64").replace('\n','')
    base64String = '<image xlink:href="data:image/jpg;base64,{0}" width="240" height="240" x="0" y="0"  />'.format(base64data)
    edited_file_name = filename.replace('.jpg','')
    f = open(edited_file_name+".svg",'wb')
    f.write(startSvgTag + base64String + defs + end_defs +  endSvgTag)
```

I'm trying to update my SVG file and add my own filters on it inside defs tags and resave the file as JPEG with filters on it.

Comment: Does your SVG display correctly in whatever viewer you are using?

Comment: @zvone Yes, it does.

Comment: I only ask because in that case it does not matter how you created the SVG. You can remove the `ConvertImage(filename)` from your question and target the question at the JPEG format and `rsvg-convert`.

Comment: @zvone but ConvertImage(filename) is where the conversion takes place; from original JPEG file. So this is what it looks like. I have a SVG file - Which gets converted JPEG; then I again convert that JPEG file back to SVG using ConvertImage(filename) function to add filters I need.Then finally convert it back to JPEG file which now returns me a empty file.

Comment: Still, the probem is in the last step only. If you have an SVG which looks as it should, and you can theoretically take a screenshot of it and save it as JPEG, then a good converter should be able to do it as well. If that does not work, it is most likely a limitation of `rsvg-convert`.

Comment: @zvone hmmm so lets say I have a SVG file and I wish to convert it to JPEG and then again convert that JPEG back to SVG; if I were to use a good convertor I should be able to see the filters used in that JPEG file orginally in SVG before it was converted to JPEG?